# Having trouble with echoing HTML in php script

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a form that show users name and I am having a little trouble with this part. The ' ' and " " marks dont quite work how they are supposed to. Im trying to echo the options in drop down menu and some how the $wholenames and the last " sign appear in the wrong part of the page. Could someone please tell me what is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks

```
 echo' "<option>'; echo $wholenames; echo'</option>"';
```

Actually I had looked it wrong it is a little bit more complex. Below you can see the code. The whole dropdown menu does not appear. The wholenames integer appears, but the menu does not...

echo'

```
      <label for="addusertogroup">Add user  to an existing group:</label>
      <select name="addusertogroup" id="addusertogroup">
      ';  if(mysql_num_rows($userresult)) 
        { 
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($userresult)) 
            { 

            $wholename = array("$row2[f_name] $row2[s_name]");

                foreach ($wholename as $wholenames) {   

                    echo "<option>$wholenames</option>";


                }
            } 
         } 
        else {
            echo "<option>No Names Present</option>";  
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work, simply do this:

```
echo "<option>";
echo $wholenames;
echo "<option>";
```

or this:

```
echo "<option>$wholenames</option>";
```

or this:

```
echo '<option>'.$wholenames.'</option>';
```

All will work, just up to you which one you pick.

Comment: Or echo '<option>'.$wholenames.'</option>';

Comment: or take out the array which doesn't look like it's needed.  `echo '<option>'.$row2[f_name].' '.$row2[s_name].'</option>';`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have `"` before `<option>` and after `</option>`

It should be something like

```
echo "<option>". echo $wholenames; echo "</option>";
```

Also, if $wholenames is an array, you'd better iterate over it:

```
foreach ($wholenames as $name){
    echo "<option>". echo $name; echo "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any text for options in a HTML SELECT box are written inside the tag. If you don't put your text between the `<option>` tags the browser will try to insert it to the select box's DOM.

So you could change your code to this:

```
echo '<option value="myvalue">"' . $wholenames . '"</option>';
```

**Haven't actually tested this code.**

Update if the Quotation mark was not meant to be in the output you would simply need to write:

```
echo '<option value="myvalue">' . $wholenames . '</option>';
```

In php you can use both " " and ' ' with strings.

Comment: Where is the broken string? Are talking about PHP seeing it as a broken string or the HTML?